# only static members can be accessed in initializers baseTextStyle

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:home_page/listbeasiswa.dart';

List<Beasiswa> beasiswa = [
  const Beasiswa(id: "1",name: "Politeknik Elektronika Negeri Surabaya", description: "Beasiswa Tahun 2019 Tanpa Ribet, Ambil yuk secepatnya ! Gratis lho.", image: "assets/images/pens.png"),
  const Beasiswa(id: "2",name: "Universitas Widya Kartika", description: "Beasiswa Tahun 2019 Tanpa Ribet, Ambil yuk secepatnya ! Gratis lho.", image: "assets/images/uwika.png"),
  const Beasiswa(id: "3",name: "Beasiswa PPA", description: "Beasiswa Tahun 2019 Tanpa Ribet, Ambil yuk secepatnya ! Gratis lho.", image: "assets/images/ppa.png"),
  const Beasiswa(id: "4",name: "Jawa Pos Exellence Capital", description: "Beasiswa Tahun 2019 Tanpa Ribet, Ambil yuk secepatnya ! Gratis lho.", image: "assets/images/jawapos.png"),
];

class Wrow extends StatelessWidget{

  static Beasiswa beasiswa;
  Wrow(beasiswa);

  final wImage = new Container(
    height: 90.0,
    width: 90.0,
    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 16.0,
    ),
    alignment: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      image: new DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        image: new AssetImage(beasiswa.image),
      )
    ),
    /*child: new Image(
      image: new AssetImage("assets/images/pens.png"),
      height: 92.0,
      width: 92.0,
    ),*/
  );

  final wCard =new Container(
    height: 124.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: new Color(0xFFEEE6FF),
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        new BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          blurRadius: 10.0,
          offset: new Offset(0.0, 10.0)
        )
      ]
    ),
  );

  final baseTextStyle = TextStyle( 
    fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
  );

  final headerTextStyle = baseTextStyle.copyWith(
    color: const Colors.black,
    fontSize: 18.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
  ); // ERROR baseTextStyle only static members can be accessed in initializers

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 16.0,
        horizontal: 24.0,
      ),
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          wCard,
          wImage,
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your post so that it is legible for us to read. We also need some context of what you were attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of the card inside of `build`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final wImage = new Container(
      height: 90.0,
      width: 90.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 16.0,
      ),
    // etc
    return new Container(
    // etc
```